# Sort fans of a Facebook page by join date

Tags: facebook

I can't seem to find a way to find out the chronological order specific users 'liked' a page.

The main purpose would be to **award say the 5000th user that joined "my" page**. However, as much data as possible is also beneficial - be it acquired via standard means (via Facebook site), or the Facebook API (which I currently know nothing about).

Comment: Not answering your question at all, but why reward the 5,000th person for being a late adopter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook terms prohibit you from providing prizes for people fanning your page - you have to offer the bonus as a sweepstakes that is accessible to all fans of your page.

For this reason, they don't let you see the order in which fans joined your page.

Answer (score -1):

I think FB deletes the data or something like that. I have tried to find the data, but seems like they keep data (which falls under current timeline) online for some time, and after that they discard it.